# I am trying check 2 of the below fields apr and aprType int he return statement , if they are non empty

Tags: java, notnull

I am trying check 2 of the below fields apr and aprType , if they are non empty.
Below is the method:

```
> public WfccApplicationEntity constructApplicationEntity(
UpdateWfccApplicationDecisionRequest request,
WfccApplicationEntity entity) {
return entity.toBuilder()
>         .statusCode(request.getStatusCode())
>         .caseNumber(request.getCaseNumber())
>         .updatedBy(request.getUpdatedBy())
>         .apr(request.getApr())
>         .aprType(request.getAprType())
>         .statusCodeUpdatedDate(now())
>         .customerId(request.getCustomerId())
>         .statusCodeUpdatedDate(now())
>         .build();
>   }
```

I want to use org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isNotBlank() to check the fields

I am not able to use if statement in the return statement

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

Include Apache Commons Lang library (`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`) in your build configuration.

If you are using Gradle, you can add the Apache Commons Lang dependency to your project's `build.gradle` file as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
}
```

Save the `build.gradle` file after adding the dependency.
Gradle will automatically download the Apache Commons Lang library and include it in your project.
Sync your project with the latest gradle file.

Then you can try to use `StringUtils.isNotBlank()` method.

Here's a sample code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public WfccApplicationEntity constructApplicationEntity(UpdateWfccApplicationDecisionRequest request, WfccApplicationEntity entity) {
    return entity.toBuilder()
            .statusCode(request.getStatusCode())
            .caseNumber(request.getCaseNumber())
            .updatedBy(request.getUpdatedBy())
            .apr(StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getApr()) ? request.getApr() : entity.getApr())
            .aprType(StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getAprType()) ? request.getAprType() : entity.getAprType())
            .statusCodeUpdatedDate(now())
            .customerId(request.getCustomerId())
            .statusCodeUpdatedDate(now())
            .build();
}
```